# Poor recepton DVR Humax 9300T

Tags: windows, mac

Someone I know has a Humax Freeview receiver / recorder  and recently the picture regularly breaks up. Because reception is fine when the aerial is plugged directly into the TV we assume there is a faulty component in the Humax.

There are hundreds of recordings stored on the Humax device. My question is - can the recordings be saved onto a computer before the Humax is discarded?

**Edit:**
After contacting Humax support the issue was multi-transmitter interference,

Comment: Have you cracked it open and put the hard drive in something to see what the contents of it are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Humax tech support, they provided the answer. Here is their response:

> The symptoms you describe are likely caused by signal interference.
>   The tuners in the Humax are quite sensitive and are susceptible to
>   interference when receiving signal from multiple transmitters.   The
>   way to resolve that, is **to manually tune into just one transmitter**.

Here are the instructions for a manual retune:

- Press the MENU button on the Humax remote,
- Using the directional buttons move to Installation and press OK,
- Enter the password (Default is “0000”)
- Move to Default Setting and press OK
- A pop up will appear, Move to YES and press OK,
- Enter the password (Default is “0000”)
- “Now initialising all setting values!” will appear, please allow a few seconds for the unit to reboot,
- After the Loader version will be followed by an AUTOMATIC SEARCH,
- STOP THE SEARCH IMMEDIATLEY, by pressing OK
- Press OK to acknowledge “No Channels Found”
  NOTE: If any channels are found during the automatic search do NOT save the Results.
- When you see the Notice “No channels are available now, Please press ok to search channels”
- Press the OK button to open the Installation menu;
- Move to “Manual Search” and Press OK

Then the five channel numbers (which identify the nearest transmitter) are entered.
The actual channel numbers used depend on your location.

- Highlight Channel and press OK
- From the List (21 – 69) select the channel number you require and press OK
- Select Search and press OK, once the search is complete Save the results
- Conduct this search for all the channel numbers below

No more problems!